# how to show the intro image only once

Tags: javascript, html

I have svg and img introduction before proceed to the main page. how I show this introduction only once? here is my code:

```
<div class="preload">
   <div class="intro">        
      <img src="svg/toreriha_text_animated.svg">
      <img class="bground" src="/img/background.png">
   </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
   setTimeout(function() {
   //After 9000 milliseconds, fade out the intro. The animation duration is 500 ms.
   $(".intro").fadeOut(500);
   }, 9000);
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by only once? Do I understand that, when the user returns to the page next time they should not see the intro?

Comment: There's nothing here which would show the image twice or more. As mentioned in the comment above, please explain more precisely what the issue is.

Comment: hi @WaisKamal yes exactly. for example when the user visit the website, the introduction will show up at first open, and when the user clicked one of the menu and back to the home/top page, the introduction will not show anymore. just like ordinary website.

Comment: Check my answer below.

Comment: @WaisKamal yes this code! but I like to show again the intro when the website was refresh. is that possible?

Comment: So if the user is in the intro page and they refresh the page, they should see the intro again?

Comment: `when the user clicked one of the menu and back to the home/top page`...how does this occur? What happens when they click the menu and go back to home? Does this occur without refreshing the whole page? You'd need to show a [mre] of your issue so we can understand precisely how to solve this within the context of your current code. Your question could have been _a lot_ clearer to begin with.

Comment: hi @WaisKamal "So if the user is in the intro page and they refresh the page, they should see the intro again?" if possible?

Comment: `So if the user is in the intro page and they refresh the page, they should see the intro again`...that should happen already with the code you've shown us (unless there's something else you haven't shown which is interfering with that). It seems like the issue with navigating the menus is the thing which you actually want solved - but as I mentioned above you haven't yet shown any code so that we could help you with that.

Comment: @maru you can store the current page url path (`window.location.pathname`) in `localStorage`, and when the page loads, check whether the current path and the stored path are equal. If they are, show the intro. However, this would also show the intro if the user navigates to another page, goes back to the homepage and reloads the homepage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to show the intro only when the user visits the page for the first time, here is a workaround: add a `hide` class to the intro. When the page loads, check for a value (`introLoaded` in this case) in `localStorage`. If it is not set, remove the `hide` class, show the intro and set the value.

```js
if (!localStorage.getItem("introLoaded")) {
  $(".intro").removeClass("hide");
  localStorage.setItem("introLoaded", "true");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".intro").fadeOut(500);
  }, 9000);
}
```

```css
.intro.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preload">
  <div class="intro hide">
    <img src="svg/toreriha_text_animated.svg">
    <img class="bground" src="/img/background.png">
  </div>
</div>
```